# NodeJS HTTP GET Request

Tags: node.js, http

I am trying to assign a websocket URL based on the response from the http server I am running. I know that the server receives and interprets the request and that it sends a response because I have it logging on the server console, but I don't know why this is not assigning that response to the variable "customerWSURL". Here is my code:

```
var req = httpClient.get(ConfigServiceURL, function(response){
    response.on('data', function(data){
        customerWSURL = data;
    });
    response.on('end', function(){
        console.log('httpClient has closed.');
    });
});
req.end();
```

If you require more code, just ask. I am using the http library as the https library does not send a get request for some reason.

Comment: "I don't know why this is not assigning that response to the variable "customerWSURL"."  How do you know that?  Your code doesn't do anything with that var.  Does the callback on your data listener receive anything?

Comment: because when I send "data" as a message and receive that message in a box on a test web page, there is the url that I require to open the socket. When I used websockets to pull this url from the configuration server, there was no problem assigning it to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much of the HTTP, and the HTTPS, module’s functionality is fairly low-level. You’re required to receive response data in chunks rather than just providing a callback function to be executed as soon as all of the data is received. You also need to parse the response data manually.

---

```
var req = httpClient.get(ConfigServiceURL, function (response) {

    let data = '';

    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;

    });

    response.on('end', function () {
        customerWSURL = data;
        console.log('httpClient has closed.');
    });

}).on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err.message);
});

req.end();
```

---

I hope this helps.